# SBT provide help for custom commands

Tags: command, sbt

How do you provide help for custom commands in sbt?

I want to display said help in case the args I have set are wrong (like putting a string in a number arg)

I also want to display the help if `help <myCommand>` is typed.

Any clues? The documentation doesn't say anything about it:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Extending/Commands.html

And google doesn't help either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#General+commands), `help` should work on `Command`s. But you need to define your `Command` correctly using one of the methods in [`Command.scala`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.11/main/command/src/main/scala/sbt/Command.scala#L41-L45), e.g.

```
commands += Command.command("foo", "bar", "baz")(...)
```

then

```
> foo<TAB>
  bar
> help foo
  baz
```

For the benefit of anybody wanting to do the same for `Task`, here's an answer...

The `help` input task is what you want users to type, e.g.

```
> help compile
Compiles sources.
```

and to provide the documentation string, you provide it when you define the key to your `Task`. e.g.

```
val compile = TaskKey[CompileAnalysis]("compile", "Compiles sources.", APlusTask)
```

Later on you assign the key to the implementation of the `Task`, like so

```
compile <<= compileTask
```

or using the new macro based API (which I detest)

```
compile := { println("hello world") ; compile.value }
```

Lots of examples in

- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala

Comment: FYI I raised a ticket for this [on ensime-sbt](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-sbt/issues/176) because it seems we're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I am defining my command as following `Command.args("myRun", "display", sbt.Help(briefHelp = ("foo", "bar")))(...)` When calling help myRun, it says `No matches for regular expression 'runFull'`. What am I doing wrong?